# Error: Could not find or load main class Java with many external JARS and Quartz Scheduling

Tags: java, eclipse, background, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to get my java program to run in the background on the given computer but I keep getting that bland java error. I have been using eclipse to develop and the directory I am in is

```
C:\Users\clind_Site2\workspace\GoldenSheetHelper\src\GSH
```

When I run `dir` in this directory I can see

```
06/29/2016  01:18 PM    <DIR>          .
06/29/2016  01:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             1,162 ADObject.class
06/09/2016  10:35 AM               950 ADObject.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             8,572 BillingReport.class
06/30/2016  09:39 AM            10,040 BillingReport.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM               791 CustomerObject.class
06/15/2016  10:24 AM               546 CustomerObject.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             4,353 HistoryReportBuilder.class
06/30/2016  09:39 AM             6,136 HistoryReportBuilder.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             7,093 MonthlyReportBuilder.class
06/30/2016  09:39 AM             8,196 MonthlyReportBuilder.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             5,183 ProgramMain.class
06/30/2016  09:34 AM             7,508 ProgramMain.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             2,085 ProgramScheduler.class
06/30/2016  10:33 AM             3,135 ProgramScheduler.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM             6,316 SQLConnection.class
06/28/2016  02:19 PM             6,738 SQLConnection.java
06/30/2016  10:38 AM               844 UserObject.class
06/22/2016  11:33 AM               549 UserObject.java
              18 File(s)         80,197 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  53,912,338,432 bytes free
```

I have set the path for the jdk so I know that can't be the issue. I run

```
javac -cp C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\Microsoft_JDBC_Driver_6.0_for_SQL_Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\sqljdbc42.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\jtds\jtds-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\quartz-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\slf4j-1.7.21\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\slf4j-1.7.21\slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar *.java
```

in order to compile and it works. I run

```
java -cp .;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\Microsoft_JDBC_Driver_6.0_for_SQL_Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\jtds\jtds-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\quartz2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\slf4j-1.7.21\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\slf4j-1.7.21\slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar ProgramScheduler

Error: Could not find or load main class ProgramScheduler
```

I realize that when I say I want to run this in the background I should use javaw but I just want to make sure it works first.

He is my code of the main I want to call:

public class ProgramScheduler {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         // specify the job' s details..
         JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ProgramMain.class)
                                   .withIdentity("mainJob")
                                   .build();
         //Retrieve new Data at 1:00am everyday
         CronTrigger cronTrigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity("crontrigger1","crontriggergroup1")
                 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 1 * * *"))
                 .build();

         //Build Monthly Reports...
         JobDetail monthlyReport = JobBuilder.newJob(MonthlyReportBuilder.class)
                                   .withIdentity("monthlyJob")
                                   .build();
         //On the first of each month at 12:00am
         CronTrigger cronTrigger2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity("crontrigger2","crontriggergroup2")
                 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 0 1 * * *"))
                 .build();

         //Build Monthly billing Report(Like one created from export button)...
         JobDetail billingReport = JobBuilder.newJob(BillingReport.class)
                 .withIdentity("monthlyBilling")
                 .build();
         //On the first of each month at 12:02am
         CronTrigger cronTrigger3 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity("crontrigger3","crontriggergroup3")
                 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 2 0 1 * * *"))
                 .build();

         //Build Monthly History Report(Like one created from export button)...
         JobDetail historyReport = JobBuilder.newJob(HistoryReportBuilder.class)
                 .withIdentity("monthlyHistory")
                 .build();
         //On the first of each month at 12:04am
         CronTrigger cronTrigger4 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity("crontrigger4","crontriggergroup4")
                 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 4 0 1 * * *"))
                 .build();

         //schedule the jobs
         SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
         Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
         sch.start();
         sch.scheduleJob(job, cronTrigger1);
         sch.scheduleJob(monthlyReport, cronTrigger2);
         sch.scheduleJob(billingReport, cronTrigger3);
         sch.scheduleJob(historyReport, cronTrigger4);

      } catch (SchedulerException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Is this something to do with quartz? I'm new to it and don't know much about it. But I am completely stumped and can't find anything through searching online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so ProgramScheduler is in no package?

Comment: Correct it is the class. GSH is the package

Comment: so you probably need to use `java ... GSH.ProgramScheduler`. Mind the [naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), though.

Comment: I tried java -cp (all the classpaths) GSH.ProgramScheduler and it gave the same error

Comment: so you are at `C:\Users\clind_Site2\workspace\GoldenSheetHelper\src\GSH` folder running `java` right? Does the `ProgramScheduler.java` contain `package GSH;`?

Comment: No it doesn't. It is the package containing all of the classes. `src` is the folder that has the package GSH in it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Thanks to @jan.supol (see comments) I realized that in command prompt I should run the package as well as the main class. EX:

```
C:\Users\clind_Site2\workspace\GoldenSheetHelper\src>java -cp .;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\Microsoft_JDBC_Driver_6.0_for_SQL_Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\sqljdbc42.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\jtds\jtds1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\quartz-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\slf4j-1.7.21\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\Users\clind_Site2\mark\slf4j-1.7.21\slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar GSH.ProgramScheduler
```

Basically I had to move back (cd ..) and run it there